# Add a space at the bottom of the body

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a parameter that is text. The text spans two pages where the text goes all the way to the footer before spanning. I need to somehow get a space between the bottom of the text and the top of the footer.

I tried increasing the page margin and the increases the footer, also tried to put a border around the body. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: With all the languages how can people see quickly what it relates to?

Comment: @user1854438 You tagged the question C#. People can filter questions by tag.

Comment: See the search [c#][rdlc] space"  at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%5Brdlc%5D+space. This is a search for all questions with the [tag:c#] and [tag:rdlc] tags and matching the word "space".